# Java: volatile enough to make classes threadsafe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, volatile

I have a question about the volatile statement in Java. Please look at this constructed example:

```
class Master {
    // Foo is a class with thread-safe methods
    public volatile Foo foo;
}

class Worker1 implements Runnable {
    protected Master master

    void run() { ... };
}

class Worker2 implements Runnable {
    protected Master master

    void run() { ... };
}
```

We have 2 worker threads which hold a reference to an object of class Master running at the same time. During their work, both have to access methods of master.foo. At some point, the Foo object of master will be changed by one of the worker threads. Now my question: Does the use of volatile make the whole construction thread-safe? I am asking this because in a [Java tutorial from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) it says

> However, there are actions you can specify that are atomic:
>
> - Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables [...]
>
> Atomic actions cannot be interleaved, so they can be used without fear of thread interference.

I just would like to make sure that I understood this correctly.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'changed'? 1. a new instance of `Foo` will be created, 2. `Foo`'s state will be modified?

Comment: Sorry for unclear statement: It is about changing the reference, not the object itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reads and writes of references are always atomic in Java, so there is no danger of, for example, seeing the reference in some half-updated state. If this is what you mean by "thread safe" then the operation is thread safe with or without the keyword.

But `volatile` is not about atomicity, it affects whether threads can cache writes locally. `volatile` would force writes to be written back to main memory and be visible to other threads. If that is what you mean by thread-safe, then yes you need this keyword.

`volatile` itself does not affect whether method calls on `foo` exclude other threads or not. If that's what you mean you want to use `synchronized`, and in a different place.

Comment: Thank you :) The second case it the one I care about :)

Comment: Amazing answer! Easy to understand!

Answer (score 4):

`volatile` ensures that a thread reading the variable will see the new value set in this variable before by another thread. It won't see a stale value stored in a processor cache.

Whether it makes the whole program thread-safe depends on what the program does, how it uses the variable, and how the Foo class is designed.

Comment: Thank you :) This also answers my question :)

Comment: The semantic of `volatile` you've described was correct up to Java 1.4. Starting 1.5, volatile has additional role. Namely it establishes _happens-before_ relation(ordering): let say `vl` is `volatile`, ff you write to `vl` all other writes (in the same thread) that happen before write to `vl` are also visible to other threads. And reading of `vl` ensures that all subsequent reads in the thread (of other variables) will have values as were at the moment of reading `vl`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this "cascading" effect of volatile. I just wanted to explain the basic functionality of volatile. BTW, Relying on this cascading effect makes things less clear and more fragile than other mechanisms, IMO, and I wouldn't advise doing it.

Answer (score 3):

volatile is not enough.

I believe this example demonstrates one situation where volatile is not enough:

Shared object:

```
public class Blammo
{
  public String kapow;
}
```

Code in thread 1:

```
Blammo blammo = new Blammo();
blammo.kapow = "zowie";
if ((blammo.kapow != null) && (blammo.kapow.isEmpty()))
{
  ...
}
```

Code in thread 2:

```
blammo.kapow = null;
```

Thread 1 is executing and executes (blammo.kapow != null).
Thread 1 swaps out and Thread 2 swaps in.
Thread 2 executes (blammo.kapow = null).
Thread 2 swaps out and Thread 1 swaps in.
Thread 1 now executes (blammo.kapow.isEmpty()) and throws a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you do is setting this variable, than yes, volatile is enough. As pointed out in the comments, you need volatile to make the changes visible (however, you will not have any corrupt updates without volatile, like you could have with long or double, see below).

By default, reading and writing of reference variables (references to objects) are atomic, as are reading and writing to most primitive types (except for long and double).

With volatile you can make sure that reads and writes to variables of type long and double are also atomic, which you don't need in this case.

So, yes, in this example, it is enough. However, if you're planning on sending more complex messages, consider using tools from java.util.concurrent.*

Comment: no not necessarily without volatile (a simple setter/getter won't be thread safe/visible)

Comment: Without the volatile keyword, the change may not be visible to other threads for an arbitrarily long time. While this does not result in inconsistencies, it is probably not the desired behavior.

Comment: volatile doesn't have an impact only on the atomicity of the operation. It also has an impact on the visibility of the value. Making it non-volatile could make the program non thread-safe.